# Rumbling noise/feeling when driving

Tags: honda, tires, axle, accident

2003 Honda Civic LX

I was recently in an accident with my vehicle, and when I drove it back from the shop, I noticed a rumbling feeling that becomes more intense as I go faster.

The only thing damaged in the accident was my headlights, hood, and bumper. The radiator, frame, and engine were all unharmed.

It kind of feels and sounds like when you have a flat tire, though not as intense. I'm sure something is rubbing or grinding against something else somewhere.

What could this be, and is it worth fixing?

Comment: Are you saying that you had the car fixed at the “shop”, meaning a car mechanic?  If so, you need to take it back to get them to look what is causing the rumbling.  Something is not right and could be dangerous.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

While you state the extent of your damage was limited to facia items, I'd suggest the problem may be a bad wheel bearing. If the wheel hit anything in the accident, it could have been enough force to damage it and cause the symptoms you describe without having damaged the tire or wheel in the process.

Comment: If lug nuts are not tight they give the same feel as a bad front wheel bearing.

Comment: Check the tightness of the lug nuts **before** you drive the car.